# Prove that $FS_4$-module is simple

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am solving the following problem:

> Consider a field $F$ with $\operatorname{char} (K)=0$, let $\sigma = (1,2)$ and $\pi = (1,2,3,4)$.

An $FS_4$-representation $\rho$ is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\rho(\sigma) &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}\right), \\
\rho(\pi) &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right).
\end{align}
$$
Let $V$ denote the $FS_4$-module corresponding to $\rho$. Prove that the $FS_4$-module $V$ is simple.

Well, I feel that the actual proof leads to showing that some particular matrix has no eigenvectors with elements in a field, but I still do not know how to start. And could you please explain what is a "module corresponging to $\rho$"? Is it just the codomain of it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you know already, but you could find the character of the representation and prove it is irreducible.  Also the module is just the vector space $V$ on which $S_4$ acts (through $\rho$)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know characters yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $V$ is reducible, the hypotheses imply that it has a subrepresentation of dimension $1$, i.e., you can find a common eigenvector for $\rho(\sigma)$ and $\rho(\pi)$.

Comment: Assuming they have covered Maschke, or did I miss something? (+1)